# Spring deployment in jboss error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I just wanted to add spring framework to my project, But when i try to deploy my war file in jboss 6.1.0 Final, it gives a error. I get following error,

```
    11:01:46,556 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initializ
ation failed
11:01:46,557 INFO  [STDOUT] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'com.tapgift.merchant.integration.spring.DaoFactoryPostProcessor#0' defined in class
path resource [config/dao-defs.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DAOFactory' while setting bea
n property 'daoFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Error creating bean with name 'DAOFactory' defined in class path resource [config/dao-defs.xml]: I
nvocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is dao-def.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- All DAO bean definitions goes here -->
    <bean id="DAOFactory"
        class="com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.jdbc.JdbcDaoFactoryImpl" />

    <bean class="com.tapgift.merchant.integration.spring.DaoFactoryPostProcessor">
        <property name="daoFactory" ref="DAOFactory" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="merchantDao"
        class="com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.jdbc.JdbcMerchantDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
        <property name="queryFactory" ref="QueryFactory" />         
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is application-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tapgift.merchant" />

    <import resource="classpath:config/spring-integration.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:config/dao-defs.xml" /> 
    <import resource="classpath:config/query-defs.xml" />   
    <import resource="classpath:config/spring-support.xml" />


</beans>
```

Finally this is web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/application-context.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

oops, almost missed the pom,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tapgift</groupId>
    <artifactId>merchant</artifactId>
    <name>merchant-server</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>               
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                   <version>3.2.1</version>
                   <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                  <version>2.6</version>
                  <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                 <version>2.0.1</version>
                 <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                 <version>1.4</version>
                 <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>           
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON view resolver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  -->       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I can see all the files compiled and assembled to the war file. Appreciate, if a spring guru can point me the reason for this deployment error.

Edit: Added DaoFactoryImpl

```
package com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.jdbc;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.BaseDao;
import com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.DaoFactory;
import com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.EntityBaseDao;

/**
 * Class <code>CaseServiceImpl</code> is an implementation of the <tt>DaoFactory</tt> interface.
 */
public class JdbcDaoFactoryImpl implements DaoFactory, InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware
{
    private ApplicationContext m_appCtx;
    private Map<String, EntityBaseDao<?>> m_daoMap = new HashMap<String, EntityBaseDao<?>>();

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}.
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, BaseDao> beanMap = m_appCtx.getBeansOfType(BaseDao.class);
        for (final BaseDao dao : beanMap.values())
        {
            m_daoMap.put(((EntityBaseDao) dao).getEntityType().getName(), (EntityBaseDao) dao);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}.
     */
    @Override
    public BaseDao getDao(String name)
    {
        return this.m_daoMap.get(name);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}.
     */
    @Override
    public <T> T getEntityDao(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        String entityName = ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) clazz.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0])
            .getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
        return clazz.cast(this.m_daoMap.get(entityName));
    }

    /**
     * Set method for m_appCtx
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appCtx) throws BeansException
    {
        this.m_appCtx = appCtx;
    }

}
```

**Update 2**
The problem seems to be creating the JdbbcDaoFactoryimpl instance, When i removed the
`<bean id="DAOFactory" class="com.tapgift.merchant.integration.db.dao.jdbc.JdbcDaoFactoryImpl" />` with its dependencies, i can deploy it without any problem. I checked the war file and all spring jars are belongs to same version. Need  a help desperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i was able to fix it, Slightly related to what Ajinkya showed.
Problem was `m_daoMap.put(((EntityBaseDao) dao).getEntityType().getName()` on this code of JdbcDaoFactoryImpl. `((EntityBaseDao) dao).getEntityType()` was not returning any value but null. I forgot to override / remove particular method of actual dao implementation class. Once i removed that method, i was able to deploy it without facing any problem.

Thank you  for your support anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Issue:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DAOFactory' while setting bean
>   property 'daoFactory';

Cause:

> Error creating bean with name 'DAOFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [config/dao-defs.xml]: **Invocation of init method failed**;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Spring not able to create object of `DAOFactory` i.e. `JdbcDaoFactoryImpl` as it came across **`NullPointerException`** while initializing object.
Add some relevant code which will help to figure out exact cause.

---

Update: 
Looks like following line is causing the issue

```
Map<String, BaseDao> beanMap = m_appCtx.getBeansOfType(BaseDao.class);
```

Spring not able to find bean of type `BaseDao`. Make sure you have defined a bean of type `BaseDao`

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, Thanks, updated the question with `JdbcDaoFactoryImpl` source.